# How do I set and get public fields from a instance of a object - C#

Tags: c#

I know that reflection can get the fields from a type. But I would like to get and set the fields of an instance of a object dynamicly. Is this possible?

Comment: If you know about reflection, can you please clarify *exactly* what it is you're asking about here?

Comment: @Jesse why do you keep mentioning a Web Software architecture? The question has nothing to do with Web. Also, even a 10 year old answer holds value, as long as it is still relevant (which it is) and answers the question (which it does). And, that's a lie, the most recent C# version released is C# 7.0 alongside Visual Studio 2017, C# 8.0 is [not even close](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/8) to release

Comment: @Jesse if the answer is still the best answer to the question, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Jesse you can try over on the [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) site, and I wish you all the best ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetField` you want to set field from the instance then use `SetValue` method.

```
 obj1.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(obj1,value);
```